# How do I grep for strings with special characters like []?

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to find all the files has text: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']`,  I tried to use `grep -rl '$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']' .`, but later on found `[]` has special meaning as search pattern. So what is the right command for searching text `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are right that `[` and `]` are special characters. Quote them with `\` or use `fgrep` instead. The latter is plain string search:

```
fgrep "\$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']" ...
```

You still need to quote `$` though because it is otherwise interpreted by `bash` and other shells.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the -F or --fixed-strings to specify a list of strings to be matched.

`grep -Frl "\$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']" /path/to/files`

[From the man page for grep:](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

> -F, --fixed-strings
>   Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (-F is specified by POSIX .)

`fgrep` is deprecated but may be still available as an alternative to `grep -F`.

Answer (score 1):

As Maxim Yegorushkin said, you have to escape the $ and [ ] characters.

```
grep -rl "\$GLOBALS\['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'\]\['SC_OPTIONS'\]" .
```